# Autocheck changes in a HTTPS website

Tags: software-rec

I need to monitor the changes (announcements from TA) that is made on a website which requires me to login. I was wondering if there is some way where I can automate this checking, so that I get notified if there's any change. I have come across browser plugins (like Page Monitor in Chrome) which does this for a normal webpage. Is there some utility where this is extended to HTTPS websites.

OS: Win 7 / Ubuntu

Comment: The title is slightly misleading: while certainly the site might be using HTTPS once you're logged in, the real problem is the login itself. Another thing to specify is what OS you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy option would be to use an RSS feed from the website, if it has one.  RSS feeds can be made to require authentication, but I am not sure if they can be encrypted.

If the site does not have a RSS feed, the harder option would be to learn Python and use the [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) or [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) frameworks to scrape the site and output the data in some form that is convenient to you.